# Что лучше при работе с базой данных на си? Выделение динамической памяти или копирование в другой файл?

Tags: c, база-данных

Сейчас в университете мы используем бинарный файл со структурами в качестве базы данных. Чтобы как-то взаимодействовать с этой бд (допустим для сортировки), я создаю новый бинарник, затем с помощью вставок из первого во второй их перемещаю.

Преподаватель сказал, что лучше выделять динамическую память, куда записывать всю бд, сортировать и перезаписывать в исходный файл.

Такой вопрос, а если бд состоит из очень большого кол-ва структур, то мы будем требовать слишком много памяти, которую система может не дать. Что в данном случае лучше?

Comment: система сама справиться с нехваткой памяти и **сама** недостачу памяти спрячет в дисковый своп (*кэш памяти*). не парьтесь.

Comment: "Очень большого" - сколько структур, какого размера?...

Comment: Спасибо всем! Получается лучше всегда использовать оперативную память.

Comment: Обработка большого количества структур, не умещающихся одновременно в оперативную память, требует большого количества различных нетривиальных алгоритмов. @AlexGlebe А разработчики БД-то и не знают, что система сама справится.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, какую-то чушь вы спороли ;) или это был сарказм?

Comment: При выделении памяти, например 30 Gig для новой таблицы будет использовано половина физической памяти, а половина свопа. Памяти хватит. А если 300 Gig, то конечно самому надо будет свой своп написать (файловый буфер). *А не проще-ли своп раздел увеличить?* Не вижу сарказма, а вижу простой выход из положения, увеличив своп раздел. @0andriy